# Equivalence relation! Make formula saying that R is not an equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, relations

I don't know how to do this particular thing.

Using quantifiers and logical links as

$$and, or, =>, <=>$$

and expressions like $$x\in A, x\notin A, R(x, y), \lnot R(x, y)$$

Make formula saying that R is not an equivalence relation on set A.

Comment: Do you know what is an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) ?

Comment: A *binary relation* $R$ on a set $A$ is an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Definition) **iff** three properties of $R$ do hold. Thus, two steps : (i) express the three properties with three formulas with quantifiers and connectives; (ii) express the fact that the *conjunction* of the three fromula is false.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, hi, I know that I should show that the conjunction is false but with given things for me to use I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Recall the definition of an equivalence relation $R$ on a set $A$. $R$ will be a subset of $A \times A$. It also satisfies three properties:

- Reflexivity: Each element is related to itself, i.e. $(x,x) \in R$.
- Symmetry: If two elements are related if and only if they're related going "both ways." (Not the best words for it but the formula clarifies it.) Explicitly, $(x,y) \in R \Leftrightarrow (y,x) \in R$.
- Transitivity: Self-explanatory. $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,z) \in R \Rightarrow (x,z) \in R$.

Begin by defining a subset $R \subseteq A \times A$ and translate the necessary properties into propositional logic and it should, within reason, all come together pretty smoothly, at least insofar as being an equivalence relation.

To be not an equivalence relation, one or more of the above properties must be false.

Comment: Hi, I know the definition and I understand it, but even though I tried I don't know how to make such formula just using only given things that I can use